# Get credentials for DataFactoryManagementClient

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-managed-identity

I have code that generates credentials to pass to a DataFactoryManagementClient. It uses an app registration to obtain credentials, as I had started it in a console app.

```
    public DataFactoryClient(string tenantId, string subscriptionId, string applicationId, string clientSecret)
    {
        AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(applicationId, clientSecret);
        AuthenticationResult result = context.AcquireTokenAsync(
            "https://management.azure.com/", clientCredential).Result;
        ServiceClientCredentials credentials = new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken);
        client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials)
        {
            SubscriptionId = subscriptionId
        };
    }
```

I moved the code to an Azure Function, now I want to get rid of the App Registration and just use the Managed Identity assigned automatically (I have enabled that)  I can't figure out how though... DataFactoryManagementClient expects a ServiceClientCredentials object but I have a ManagedIdentityCredential object.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Hi, if my reply is helpful, please accept it, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the system-assigned identity of the azure function with `DataFactoryManagementClient`, you could use [`AzureServiceTokenProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/service-to-service-authentication#using-the-library), when you publish your code to the azure function, it will use the system-assigned identity of your function automatically.

**Note:** When you use the code, please create a connection string [`AzureServicesAuthConnectionString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/service-to-service-authentication#connection-string-support) for your function app first, to use system-assigned identity, its value should be `RunAs=App`.

Sample(I test it in local to get an ADF, it automatically uses the VS sign-in account to auth, in azure function, it uses the system-assigned identity):

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using Microsoft.Rest;

namespace ConsoleApp11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            string accessToken = azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/").Result;
            string subscriptionId = "xxxxxxxx";
            ServiceClientCredentials credentials = new TokenCredentials(accessToken);
            var client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials)
            {
                SubscriptionId = subscriptionId
            };
            var a = client.Factories.Get("group-name","joyfactory");
            System.Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]